# Set Some conditions to answer my question

Tags: support, answers, asking-questions, limits, specialist-badge

Suppose I wish to allow only users who have scored at least 15 in the particular tag to answer my question, Is it possible to set a condition like this while asking a question? So that I can avoid strangers/answers from dummy users.

Comment: How much rep do you think experts have when they start using Stack Overflow? Well, they have 1 like everyone else. You could be missing great answers with such filters.

Comment: And OMG, what about people who aren't even on Stack Overflow? Knuth? Pfft! He has no SO reputation, what does he know? [rolls eyes]

Comment: @Raj: Remember [voting on Meta is different than normal SE sites](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: @JackManey In fairness, I think Raj is just not really up on how things work around here, and may have an issue with language/culture. I think he's just trying to release us from feeling obligated to continue to help with this question.

Comment: By the way Raj, welcome to Meta Stack Overflow! Downvotes just signify the community disagrees with your request, and they don't really mean much. Just spend some more time on MSO and on SO and you'll learn more about the platform. With that said, we do encourage ideas, just search first. ;)  Good luck man! :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Why can't you ignore those answer if reputation is less than 15? See everyone start their reputation from 1. We can't say all people who has reputation less than 15 are strangers.

Its a nice thought. One of my best suggestion for this site is to allow only right name and right photo. 
Example: Raj - looks right name/hims056 looks like dummy. In case of photo, ur's dummy and hims056 used right one !!!

Comment: How would a particular name or photo make someone better at answering questions?!

Answer (score 17):

Currently no. If it is a feature-request, I disagree with it because new users can also give useful answers. See [new users can also give useful answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=newusers). E.g. [Olaf Dietsche](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1741542/olaf-dietsche?tab=answers) or [Roman Pekar.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1744834/roman-pekar?tab=answers)

As @jmort253 said in [his comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154998/is-it-possible-to-set-some-conditions-to-answer-my-question#comment445147_154999): a user posting an answer to your question can not prevent others (or experts) from doing so.

Comment: @Raj - Expertise has not been shown to correlate with a Stack Overflow reputation score.

Comment: No, you don't need this feature. There are many expert programmers out there who have only 1 reputation because they are busy working instead of posting questions and answers on Stack Overflow. ;)  Besides, it's not like a user posting an answer to your question will prevent others from doing so.

Answer (score 7):

I strongly disagree with this as let say who has more experience who can give better useful answers and yet the have just joined SO.

In that case it would not be justice as who asked question will loose opportunity to get nice answers and will also apply to others who are seeking answer for such questions.

And again `Restrictive Knowledge Sharing` is not part of SO as all the users here can access all the question/answer of any language and with any kind of reputation.

And also some times possible to happen like answers given by users who scored `'3k'` may not be exact answer you were looking for.

Comment: Where did ,.;?! have gone? I miss those guys!